# Why is the rgba background value in this css block invalid?

Tags: css

This [CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) says the background value in this css block is invalid:

```
.sticky_scroll_box2 {
  background: rgba(0.95, 0, 0, 0.05);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
  opacity:1;
  z-index: 13;
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: The validator tells you why: "Value Error : background Invalid RGB function".

Comment: [`rgba()`'s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgb()_and_rgba()) 1st argument could be either `95%` or `242` (about 95% of 255).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thank you! I'll check about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS validator says the background value in this css block is invalid because RGBA value can't be in decimal (besides the opacity/transparency)

RGBA only accepts integer, by using a number in floating point, CSS validator will throw an error

You need to change your css to

```
body {
    background: rgba(1, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept your answer when I can (in 6 minutes)

Comment: Haha. Thanks please do @Emilio

Answer (score 3):

RGB only accepts integer numbers (0-255), only the Alpha accepts floats (0.00 - 1.00). You are using float for the Red value.

From this:

```
background: rgba(0.95, 0, 0, 0.05);
```

To this:

```
background: rgba(1, 0, 0, 0.05);
```